# If a short exact sequence ends in a free module, then it admits a section

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, free-modules

> Consider the short exact sequence of $R$-modules
> $$
>   0 \to A \to B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0 \,.
> $$
> Now suppose that $C$ is a free $R$-module. Show that there is a section map $s \colon C\to B$ such that $g \circ s = \mathrm{id}_C$.

I can't come up with with $s$ explicitly so I guess I can't do that but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $C$ is free with basis $X=\{x_i\}$, then module Homs $C\to B$ are in bijection with set maps $X\to B$. Can you now find an appropriate choice for the images of each $x_i$?

Comment: I've been trying to use your hint, but I don't understand completely what you mean

Comment: The map $g$ is onto, so for each $i$ take any $b_i\in B$ with $g(b_i)=x_i$. Now define a set map $s:X\to B$ via $s(x_i):=b_i$, which by freeness uniquely extends to a module map $s:C\to B$.